# Sequence with different intervals in R: matching sensor data

Tags: r, time-series, sequence, sensors, matching

I need a vector that repeats numbers in a sequence at varying intervals. I basically need this

```
 c(rep(1:42, each=6), rep(43:64, each = 7),
 rep(65:106, each=6), rep(107:128, each = 7),
```

.... but I need to this to keep going, until almost 2 million. 
So I want a vector that looks like

```
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
.....
[252] 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 
....
[400] 64 64 64 64 64 64 65 65 65 65 65 65...
```

and so on. Not just alternating between 6 and 7 repetitions, rather mostly 6s and fewer 7s until the whole vector is something like 1.7 million rows. So, is there a loop I can do? Or apply, replicate?  I need the 400th entry in the vector to be 64, the 800th entry to be 128, and so on, in somewhat evenly spaced integers.

### UPDATE

Thank you all for the quick clever tricks there. It worked, at least well enough for the deadline I was dealing with.  I realize repeating 6 xs and 7 xs are a really dumb way to try to solve this, but it was quick at least. But now that I have some time, I would like to get everyone's opinions /ideas on my real underlying issue here.

I have two datasets to merge. They are both sensor datasets, both with stopwatch time as primary keys. But one records every 1/400 of a second, and the other records every 1/256 of a second. I have trimmed the top of each so that they are starting the exact same moment. But.. now what? I have 400 records for each second in one set, and 256 records for 1 second in the other. Is there a way to merge these without losing data? Interpolating or just repeating obs is a-ok, necessary, I think, but I'd rather not throw any data out.
I read [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457818/matching-time-vectors-of-different-length-a-tricky-one), that had to do with using xts and zoo for a very similar problem to mine. But they have nice epoch date/times for each. I just have these awful fractions of seconds!

```
sample data (A):
       time dist a_lat
1  139.4300   22     0
2  139.4325   22     0
3  139.4350   22     0
4  139.4375   22     0
5  139.4400   22     0
6  139.4425   22     0
7  139.4450   22     0
8  139.4475   22     0
9  139.4500   22     0
10 139.4525   22     0

sample data (B):
      timestamp  hex_acc_x  hex_acc_y hex_acc_z 
1  367065215501 -0.5546875 -0.7539062 0.1406250  
2  367065215505 -0.5468750 -0.7070312 0.2109375  
3  367065215509 -0.4218750 -0.6835938 0.1796875  
4  367065215513 -0.5937500 -0.7421875 0.1562500  
5  367065215517 -0.6757812 -0.7773438 0.2031250  
6  367065215521 -0.5937500 -0.8554688 0.2460938 
7  367065215525 -0.6132812 -0.8476562 0.2109375 
8  367065215529 -0.3945312 -0.8906250 0.2031250 
9  367065215533 -0.3203125 -0.8906250 0.2226562 
10 367065215537 -0.3867188 -0.9531250 0.2578125
```

(oh yeah, and btw, the B dataset timestamps are epoch format * 256, because life is hard. i haven't converted it for this because dataset A has nothing like that, only just 0.0025 intervals. Also the B data sensor was left on for hours later the A data sensor turned off, so that doesn't help)

Comment: @akrun yes its slightly different

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar  I haven't looked it closely, but may be slight modification of that solution will make it right here

Comment: Thanks! yeah if I could get that to work, I could make 2 vectors and then combine and sort! But I'm having trouble getting that to work for the multiple sequences.

Comment: I guess one option would be `n <- 4; indx <- rep(seq(n), rep(c(42,22), n/2));n1 <- 128; lst <- split(seq(n1), indx);lst[c(TRUE, FALSE)] <- lapply(lst[c(TRUE, FALSE)],function(x) rep(x, each=6));lst[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- lapply(lst[c(FALSE, TRUE)],function(x) rep(x, each=7));unlist(lst)`

Comment: When you say "not just alternating between 6 7 and repetitions", how do you determine how many times `each` a given chunk of numbers is repeated? Is it always 42 then 22 then 42 then 22 ...?

Comment: @r2evans, plz see my update for the overview of the real problem. the 6 7 thing was not determined by anything really, other than guessing to make this work (265 into 400, many times over).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you put it that way ... I have absolutely no idea how you are planning on using all of the 6s and 7s. :-)

Regardless, I recommend standardizing the time, adding a "sample" column, and merging on them. Having the "sample" column may facilitate your processing later on, perhaps.

Your data:

```
df400 <- structure(list(time = c(139.43, 139.4325, 139.435, 139.4375, 139.44, 139.4425,
                                 139.445, 139.4475, 139.45, 139.4525),
                        dist = c(22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L),
                        a_lat = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)),
                   .Names = c("time", "dist", "a_lat"),
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

df256 <- structure(list(timestamp = c(367065215501, 367065215505, 367065215509, 367065215513,
                                      367065215517, 367065215521, 367065215525, 367065215529, 
                                      367065215533, 367065215537),
                        hex_acc_x = c(-0.5546875, -0.546875, -0.421875, -0.59375, -0.6757812,
                                      -0.59375, -0.6132812, -0.3945312, -0.3203125, -0.3867188),
                        hex_acc_y = c(-0.7539062, -0.7070312, -0.6835938, -0.7421875,
                                      -0.7773438, -0.8554688, -0.8476562, -0.890625,
                                      -0.890625, -0.953125),
                        hex_acc_z = c(0.140625, 0.2109375, 0.1796875, 0.15625, 0.203125,
                                      0.2460938, 0.2109375, 0.203125, 0.2226562, 0.2578125)),
                   .Names = c("timestamp", "hex_acc_x", "hex_acc_y", "hex_acc_z"),
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Standardize your time frames:

```
colnames(df256)[1] <- 'time'
df400$time <- df400$time - df400$time[1]
df256$time <- (df256$time - df256$time[1]) / 256
```

Assign a label for easy reference (not that the `NA`s won't be clear enough):

```
df400 <- cbind(sample='A', df400, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df256 <- cbind(sample='B', df256, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

And now for the merge and sorting:

```
dat <- merge(df400, df256, by=c('sample', 'time'), all.x=TRUE, all.y=TRUE)
dat <- dat[order(dat$time),]
dat
##    sample     time dist a_lat  hex_acc_x  hex_acc_y hex_acc_z
## 1       A 0.000000   22     0         NA         NA        NA
## 11      B 0.000000   NA    NA -0.5546875 -0.7539062 0.1406250
## 2       A 0.002500   22     0         NA         NA        NA
## 3       A 0.005000   22     0         NA         NA        NA
## 4       A 0.007500   22     0         NA         NA        NA
## 5       A 0.010000   22     0         NA         NA        NA
## 6       A 0.012500   22     0         NA         NA        NA
## 7       A 0.015000   22     0         NA         NA        NA
## 12      B 0.015625   NA    NA -0.5468750 -0.7070312 0.2109375
## 8       A 0.017500   22     0         NA         NA        NA
## 9       A 0.020000   22     0         NA         NA        NA
## 10      A 0.022500   22     0         NA         NA        NA
## 13      B 0.031250   NA    NA -0.4218750 -0.6835938 0.1796875
## 14      B 0.046875   NA    NA -0.5937500 -0.7421875 0.1562500
## 15      B 0.062500   NA    NA -0.6757812 -0.7773438 0.2031250
## 16      B 0.078125   NA    NA -0.5937500 -0.8554688 0.2460938
## 17      B 0.093750   NA    NA -0.6132812 -0.8476562 0.2109375
## 18      B 0.109375   NA    NA -0.3945312 -0.8906250 0.2031250
## 19      B 0.125000   NA    NA -0.3203125 -0.8906250 0.2226562
## 20      B 0.140625   NA    NA -0.3867188 -0.9531250 0.2578125
```

I'm guessing your data was just a small representation. If I've guessed poorly (that A's integers are seconds and B's integers are 1/400ths of a second) then just scale differently. Either way, by resetting the first value to zero and then merging/sorting, they are easy to merge and sort.

Comment: Ahh, this is interesting. Yes you guessed right about the seconds integers. I'm going to use this, definitely should work.

Comment: It was interesting ... I had never run into `epoch*256` (or dealing with integers that large), so seeing *R* deal with them non-intuitively was enlightening. (*This* is how I learn more "stuff" in/about *R*. :-)

Comment: about the original plan, augh these were actually 2 separate similar problems, should have specified. that was for a similar problem with intervals of 1/64th of a second (still not a great plan, i know. it was a colleagues suggestion). i just have a bunch of these sets in all different formats. this works for all! =)
really, thank you so much. its my first post here and i'll definitely be back, hopefully getting better, and helping others with much easier stuff

Comment: Welcome to SO, then! Please take the time to mark one of these answers as "accepted" when the question is resolved (whether mine or not, my aim is not selfish). It's a courtesy and a way to "close the question/discussion".

Answer (score 2):

Or if you like, you can try this using `apply`

```
# using this sample data
df <- data.frame(from=c(1,4,7,11), to = c(3,6,10,13),rep=c(6,7,6,7));

> df
#  from to rep
#1    1  3   6
#2    4  6   7
#3    7 10   6
#4   11 13   7

unlist(apply(df, 1, function(x) rep(x['from']:x['to'], each=x['rep'])))    
# [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
#[26]  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  8
#[51]  8  9  9  9  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 12 12 12 12 12
#[76] 12 12 13 13 13 13 13 13 13
```

Comment: nice, this addresses my questions/comment in the question since the third column `rep` can easily be populated by a function to capture the changing ratio of 6-to-7

Answer (score 0):

```
alt <- data.frame(len=c(42,22),rep=c(6,7));
alt;
##   len rep
## 1  42   6
## 2  22   7
altrep <- function(alt,cyc,len) {
    cyclen <- sum(alt$len*alt$rep);
    if (missing(cyc)) {
        if (missing(len)) {
            cyc <- 1;
            len <- cyc*cyclen;
        } else {
            cyc <- ceiling(len/cyclen);
        };
    } else if (missing(len)) {
        len <- cyc*cyclen;
    };
    if (isTRUE(all.equal(len,0))) return(integer());
    result <- rep(1:(cyc*sum(alt$len)),rep(rep(alt$rep,alt$len),cyc));
    length(result) <- len;
    result;
};
altrep(alt,2);
##   [1]   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   3   3   3   3   3   3   4   4   4   4   4   4   5   5   5   5   5   5   6   6   6   6   6   6   7   7   7   7   7   7   8   8   8   8   8   8   9   9   9
##  [52]   9   9   9  10  10  10  10  10  10  11  11  11  11  11  11  12  12  12  12  12  12  13  13  13  13  13  13  14  14  14  14  14  14  15  15  15  15  15  15  16  16  16  16  16  16  17  17  17  17  17  17
## [103]  18  18  18  18  18  18  19  19  19  19  19  19  20  20  20  20  20  20  21  21  21  21  21  21  22  22  22  22  22  22  23  23  23  23  23  23  24  24  24  24  24  24  25  25  25  25  25  25  26  26  26
## [154]  26  26  26  27  27  27  27  27  27  28  28  28  28  28  28  29  29  29  29  29  29  30  30  30  30  30  30  31  31  31  31  31  31  32  32  32  32  32  32  33  33  33  33  33  33  34  34  34  34  34  34
## [205]  35  35  35  35  35  35  36  36  36  36  36  36  37  37  37  37  37  37  38  38  38  38  38  38  39  39  39  39  39  39  40  40  40  40  40  40  41  41  41  41  41  41  42  42  42  42  42  42  43  43  43
## [256]  43  43  43  43  44  44  44  44  44  44  44  45  45  45  45  45  45  45  46  46  46  46  46  46  46  47  47  47  47  47  47  47  48  48  48  48  48  48  48  49  49  49  49  49  49  49  50  50  50  50  50
## [307]  50  50  51  51  51  51  51  51  51  52  52  52  52  52  52  52  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  54  54  54  54  54  54  54  55  55  55  55  55  55  55  56  56  56  56  56  56  56  57  57  57  57  57  57  57
## [358]  58  58  58  58  58  58  58  59  59  59  59  59  59  59  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  61  61  61  61  61  61  61  62  62  62  62  62  62  62  63  63  63  63  63  63  63  64  64  64  64  64  64  64  65  65
## [409]  65  65  65  65  66  66  66  66  66  66  67  67  67  67  67  67  68  68  68  68  68  68  69  69  69  69  69  69  70  70  70  70  70  70  71  71  71  71  71  71  72  72  72  72  72  72  73  73  73  73  73
## [460]  73  74  74  74  74  74  74  75  75  75  75  75  75  76  76  76  76  76  76  77  77  77  77  77  77  78  78  78  78  78  78  79  79  79  79  79  79  80  80  80  80  80  80  81  81  81  81  81  81  82  82
## [511]  82  82  82  82  83  83  83  83  83  83  84  84  84  84  84  84  85  85  85  85  85  85  86  86  86  86  86  86  87  87  87  87  87  87  88  88  88  88  88  88  89  89  89  89  89  89  90  90  90  90  90
## [562]  90  91  91  91  91  91  91  92  92  92  92  92  92  93  93  93  93  93  93  94  94  94  94  94  94  95  95  95  95  95  95  96  96  96  96  96  96  97  97  97  97  97  97  98  98  98  98  98  98  99  99
## [613]  99  99  99  99 100 100 100 100 100 100 101 101 101 101 101 101 102 102 102 102 102 102 103 103 103 103 103 103 104 104 104 104 104 104 105 105 105 105 105 105 106 106 106 106 106 106 107 107 107 107 107
## [664] 107 107 108 108 108 108 108 108 108 109 109 109 109 109 109 109 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 113 113 113 113 113 113 113 114 114 114 114 114 114 114
## [715] 115 115 115 115 115 115 115 116 116 116 116 116 116 116 117 117 117 117 117 117 117 118 118 118 118 118 118 118 119 119 119 119 119 119 119 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 121 121 121 121 121 121 121 122 122
## [766] 122 122 122 122 122 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 124 124 124 124 124 124 124 125 125 125 125 125 125 125 126 126 126 126 126 126 126 127 127 127 127 127 127 127 128 128 128 128 128 128 128
altrep(alt,len=1000);
##   [1]   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   3   3   3   3   3   3   4   4   4   4   4   4   5   5   5   5   5   5   6   6   6   6   6   6   7   7   7   7   7   7   8   8   8   8   8   8   9   9   9
##  [52]   9   9   9  10  10  10  10  10  10  11  11  11  11  11  11  12  12  12  12  12  12  13  13  13  13  13  13  14  14  14  14  14  14  15  15  15  15  15  15  16  16  16  16  16  16  17  17  17  17  17  17
## [103]  18  18  18  18  18  18  19  19  19  19  19  19  20  20  20  20  20  20  21  21  21  21  21  21  22  22  22  22  22  22  23  23  23  23  23  23  24  24  24  24  24  24  25  25  25  25  25  25  26  26  26
## [154]  26  26  26  27  27  27  27  27  27  28  28  28  28  28  28  29  29  29  29  29  29  30  30  30  30  30  30  31  31  31  31  31  31  32  32  32  32  32  32  33  33  33  33  33  33  34  34  34  34  34  34
## [205]  35  35  35  35  35  35  36  36  36  36  36  36  37  37  37  37  37  37  38  38  38  38  38  38  39  39  39  39  39  39  40  40  40  40  40  40  41  41  41  41  41  41  42  42  42  42  42  42  43  43  43
## [256]  43  43  43  43  44  44  44  44  44  44  44  45  45  45  45  45  45  45  46  46  46  46  46  46  46  47  47  47  47  47  47  47  48  48  48  48  48  48  48  49  49  49  49  49  49  49  50  50  50  50  50
## [307]  50  50  51  51  51  51  51  51  51  52  52  52  52  52  52  52  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  54  54  54  54  54  54  54  55  55  55  55  55  55  55  56  56  56  56  56  56  56  57  57  57  57  57  57  57
## [358]  58  58  58  58  58  58  58  59  59  59  59  59  59  59  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  61  61  61  61  61  61  61  62  62  62  62  62  62  62  63  63  63  63  63  63  63  64  64  64  64  64  64  64  65  65
## [409]  65  65  65  65  66  66  66  66  66  66  67  67  67  67  67  67  68  68  68  68  68  68  69  69  69  69  69  69  70  70  70  70  70  70  71  71  71  71  71  71  72  72  72  72  72  72  73  73  73  73  73
## [460]  73  74  74  74  74  74  74  75  75  75  75  75  75  76  76  76  76  76  76  77  77  77  77  77  77  78  78  78  78  78  78  79  79  79  79  79  79  80  80  80  80  80  80  81  81  81  81  81  81  82  82
## [511]  82  82  82  82  83  83  83  83  83  83  84  84  84  84  84  84  85  85  85  85  85  85  86  86  86  86  86  86  87  87  87  87  87  87  88  88  88  88  88  88  89  89  89  89  89  89  90  90  90  90  90
## [562]  90  91  91  91  91  91  91  92  92  92  92  92  92  93  93  93  93  93  93  94  94  94  94  94  94  95  95  95  95  95  95  96  96  96  96  96  96  97  97  97  97  97  97  98  98  98  98  98  98  99  99
## [613]  99  99  99  99 100 100 100 100 100 100 101 101 101 101 101 101 102 102 102 102 102 102 103 103 103 103 103 103 104 104 104 104 104 104 105 105 105 105 105 105 106 106 106 106 106 106 107 107 107 107 107
## [664] 107 107 108 108 108 108 108 108 108 109 109 109 109 109 109 109 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 113 113 113 113 113 113 113 114 114 114 114 114 114 114
## [715] 115 115 115 115 115 115 115 116 116 116 116 116 116 116 117 117 117 117 117 117 117 118 118 118 118 118 118 118 119 119 119 119 119 119 119 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 121 121 121 121 121 121 121 122 122
## [766] 122 122 122 122 122 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 124 124 124 124 124 124 124 125 125 125 125 125 125 125 126 126 126 126 126 126 126 127 127 127 127 127 127 127 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 129 129 129 129
## [817] 129 129 130 130 130 130 130 130 131 131 131 131 131 131 132 132 132 132 132 132 133 133 133 133 133 133 134 134 134 134 134 134 135 135 135 135 135 135 136 136 136 136 136 136 137 137 137 137 137 137 138
## [868] 138 138 138 138 138 139 139 139 139 139 139 140 140 140 140 140 140 141 141 141 141 141 141 142 142 142 142 142 142 143 143 143 143 143 143 144 144 144 144 144 144 145 145 145 145 145 145 146 146 146 146
## [919] 146 146 147 147 147 147 147 147 148 148 148 148 148 148 149 149 149 149 149 149 150 150 150 150 150 150 151 151 151 151 151 151 152 152 152 152 152 152 153 153 153 153 153 153 154 154 154 154 154 154 155
## [970] 155 155 155 155 155 156 156 156 156 156 156 157 157 157 157 157 157 158 158 158 158 158 158 159 159 159 159 159 159 160 160
```

You can specify `len=1.7e6` (and omit the `cyc` argument) to get exactly 1.7 million elements, or you can get a whole number of cycles using `cyc`.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
len <- 2e6
step <- 400

x <- rep(64 * seq(0, ceiling(len / step) - 1), each = step) + 
        sort(rep(1:64, length.out = step))

x <- x[seq(len)] # to get rid of extra elements
```